# Updated custom repository with new packages but while running spacewalk-repo-sync it says "No new packages to sync."

Tags: repository, spacewalk

I'm using Spacewalk 2.6 and want to sync my custom repository with Spacewalk.
I am using Pulp for this repo and it works fine. Even the new packages can be found in my custom repository.

There are 416 Packages now in this repository.

When I use spacewalk-repo-sync -c "CHANNEL" it tells me Packages in repo: 411 and "Now new packages to Sync".

Is there any mechanism which prevent the repo-sync from getting newer information from the Repository?

Comment: what does the log says in /var/log/rhn/reposync.log?

Comment: It referred to another log (the one of channel) in /var/log/rhn/reposync/"CHANNEL".log and there it says "No new packages to sync."

Comment: Can you please paste content of /etc/rhn/rhn.conf?

Comment: sure i added the conf in the a seperate answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to clean cache on HTTP Proxy server:

```
rm -Rf /var/cache/rhn/*
```

And then try to sync repo with spacewalk-repo-sync command again.

Answer (score 0):

I think while repo-sync spacewalk is not getting the informations that there are new packages. Spacewalk may cache those informations somewhere and renewing it by himself after a while.
I also tried with other repositories but it's always the same. I've also got an old Spacewalk-System which worked fine and doesn't has this Problem.

Anyway here is my config file /etc/rhn/rhn.conf:

```
traceback_mail = admins@mail.com
mount_point = /var/satellite
kickstart_mount_point = /var/satellite
repomd_cache_mount_point = /var/cache
server.satellite.rhn_parent = satellite.rhn.redhat.com

# Use proxy FQDN, or FQDN:port
server.satellite.http_proxy =
server.satellite.http_proxy_username =
server.satellite.http_proxy_password =
server.satellite.ca_chain = /usr/share/rhn/RHNS-CA-CERT

# Completely disable ISS.
# If set to 1, then no slave will be able to sync from this server
# this option does not affect ability to sync to this server from
# another spacewalk (or hosted).
disable_iss=0

db_backend = postgresql
db_user = rhnuser
db_password = rhnpw
db_name = rhnschema
db_host =
db_port =
db_ssl_enabled =

server.nls_lang = english.UTF8

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.postgresql.Driver
hibernate.connection.driver_proto=jdbc:postgresql


web.satellite = 1
web.satellite_install =

web.session_swap_secret_1 = 91f0c661b2d42f88b27b051132686ecf689c197a8f866bb4effcd8b8a3620953
web.session_swap_secret_2 = 6d8d4a0aad93707a88c5de0b3d11c464f683397bace2435b578cacfdfedfc229
web.session_swap_secret_3 = 9eff8debd4f282f06d0a2f9520f7cbc848353e3c1a7a00d87c04a5a3eeb10eaf
web.session_swap_secret_4 = fc0b5bc50a591fc54a1c804f32aadd0e752edcbe36e5dd99ff859e6b30346a37

session_secret_1 = 3b2e2274dea4038c01df37fd7591f92406054c3b602176c8670b6f52ba6c0196
session_secret_2 = 670feb4501a7f05e3b92fbdfd72237293d85c2ae593d0dfa42cdbdfd52af6d12
session_secret_3 = 11efbb28f34eddcb6ed2e317e6108c920bf5f27d735d13dd84eb22fb74e9cf03
session_secret_4 = e34e09475a4e6794b390cec092287ba8f744f456b73e3f552d85e1b825c479a0

server.secret_key = f9171918471dfe770e5ce3296d5132d6a3cd89b66fb3b09016d28d349668dfb0

encrypted_passwords = 1

web.restrict_mail_domains =

web.ssl_available = 1

# OSA configuration #

server.jabber_server = spacewalk.domain.com
osa-dispatcher.jabber_server = spacewalk.domain.com

# set up SSL on the dispatcher
osa-dispatcher.osa_ssl_cert = /var/www/html/pub/RHN-ORG-TRUSTED-SSL-CERT

# system snapshots enabled
enable_snapshots = 1

#cobbler host name
cobbler.host = spacewalk.domain.com

osa-dispatcher.debug = 5
```

Comment: Right so clear the cache "rm -Rf /var/cache/rhn/*" and reposync again. Might restart httpd as well on pulp host.

Comment: This was the solution! Thank you, may you write that as an extra answere so i can upvote it for other people?